# Cannot find an option to create Java EE project in Intellij Idea Community Edition. Is it possible?

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

[Here is the screenshot of the view when I create a new project in Intellij.
I don't get any option for Java EE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9XUu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaEE is supported in Ultimate Edition only: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html